AFter an ajax request - the table is not populated with a new record
In a typescript file I have the following functions which on click of a button makes an ajax request to add the values to the database.
static bindAddForm() {        
        TaxIndex.showHelperMessage(helperText);
        $("#addTaxForm").submit(e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (typeof dataLayer !== "undefined") {
                dataLayer.push({ 'event': "my_acc_tax_entry_add_button_clicked" });
            }
            const taxId = $('#add-tax-input').val();
            const countryCode = $('#dllCountry').data('selected-value');
            if (!taxId || !countryCode) {
                $("#add-tax-input-error").removeClass('hidden');
                return;
            }
            var spinner = $('.page-spinner');
            spinner.startSpinning();
            $("#add-tax-input-error").addClass('hidden');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/account/taxes/AddTax',
                data: {
                    taxId: taxId,
                    countryCode: countryCode
                },
                success(response) {
                    TaxIndex.showNotification(response);                    
                    if (response.IsSuccessful) {
                        $('#add-tax-input').val('');
                        $("#eudoc-no").attr('checked', 'checked');
                    }
                    
                },
                complete: () => {
                    spinner.stopSpinning();    
                }
            });
        });
    }
    

You see on successful response we invoke showNotification - which just shows a notification box and most importantly invokes LoadData method which again makes an ajax request to get the data (which now should include the one that has been just entered) and update the datagrid.
tatic showNotification(response) {
     var notificationBox = $("#notificationBox");
     notificationBox
         .removeClass('alert-success')
         .removeClass('alert-danger')
         .html(response.Message).show();
     if (response.IsSuccessful) {
         notificationBox.addClass('alert-success');
         console.log('successful response in Show Notifications.');
         TaxIndex.loadData();
     } else {
         notificationBox.addClass('alert-danger');
     }
 }

and this is LoadData that invokes generateTable to update the datagrid.
static loadData() {
        const spinner = $('.page-spinner');
        spinner.startSpinning();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: "/account/taxes/GetTaxes",
            success: (taxes) => {
                console.log('taxes length' + taxes.length);
                spinner.stopSpinning();
                if (taxes.length === 0) {
                    $('#tblTaxesContainer').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $('#tblTaxesContainer').removeClass('hidden');
                    TaxIndex.generateTaxTable(taxes);
                }
            }
        });
    }

Here is
static generateTaxTable(taxes) {

    $("#tblTaxes").empty();
        $.each(taxes,
        (taxRowIndex) => {

            var rowData = taxes[taxRowIndex];
            var row = $("<tr>" +
                "<td>" + rowData.TaxNumber + "</td>" +
                "<td class='text-center'>" + rowData.CountryCode + "</td>" +
                "<td class='text-center'>" + rowData.Status + "</td>" +
                "</tr>");
            const InvalidTaxStatus = 2;
            if (rowData.StatusId === InvalidTaxStatus) {
                row.addClass('text-secondary');
            }
            $('#tblTaxes').append(row);
        });
}

The question is: why sometimes although I see the value in the database entered and you see we invoke LoadData - the datagrid doesn't show the new value. Only after refreshing the browser you see the entered value. Thanks

When using a debugger, when the problem occurs, is TaxIndex.generateTaxTable(taxes) invoked at all?  Does taxes contain the data you expect?  Please provide more specific debugging details.

Sorry, need a little clarity....
Sometimes you see the value in the db? But 'Always' only after refreshing you see in the datagrid?

So it could be cachig issue, you could add a timestamp to the request to force it to bust the cache:
$.ajax({
    ...
    url: `/account/taxes/GetTaxes?_=${new Date().getTime()}`,
    ...
});

Or it might not be in the database by the time you're doing the request so maybe you could ad a delay before loading the data again.
if (response.IsSuccessful) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        TaxIndex.loadData();
    }, 200); // 200ms delay
}

